# How to search on Google Places API using HTTPie

Tags: python, google-places, httpie

The following works in curl

```
curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=my_key"
```

The following does not working in HTTPie

```
http https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json location='-33.8670522,151.1957362' radius=500 types='food' name='cruise' key='my_key'
```

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `==` key-value separator needs to be used to specify URL parameters with HTTPie (single `=` is only used for form data or JSON). So to construct the URL, you could do:

```
$ http https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json \
    location=='-33.8670522,151.1957362' radius==500 types=='food' name=='cruise' key=='my_key'
```

(Note: you could also just use the full URL like you did in the `curl` example.)

More details here: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#request-items